# If $f(X)$ is open in $S$ then implies $X$ is open in $[0,2]$ Yes/No

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $S$ be the unit circle in the complex plane with the induced topology from $\mathbb{C}$
and let $f :[0,2]\rightarrow S$ be defined as $f(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$

Is the following statements are true?

If $f(X)$ is open in $S$  then its  implies $X$ is open in $[0,2]$.

I thinks  this stateement is true as  open map to open

Comment: What happens for $X=[0, 1.5]$?

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, you'll get that if $Y$ is open in $S$, then $f^{-1}(Y)$ is open in $[0,2]$

Comment: @Severin if i take  $X = [0,1.5]$ then $f(X)  = S$

Comment: Indeed, is $S$ open in $S$? And is $[0,1.5]$ open in $S$?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven No  it will be closed

Comment: Which one will not be open? $S$ or $[0, 1.5]$?

Comment: i thinks  f(x)  will not open

Comment: But $f(X)=S$. So you claim $S$ is not open in $S$?

Comment: yes yaa   @ Severin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

We look at the set $X=(0,1/2]\cup (1,7/4)$, and we see that $f$ is periodic with period $1$, hence $f(X)=\{e^{2\pi i t} \: | \: t\in (0,3/4)\}$. This is an open set in S, but X is not open in $[0,2]$.

It is notable, that it does hold for injective functions such as $g:[0,1)\rightarrow S$, $g(t)=e^{2\pi i t}$, since for injective functions we have that $g^{-1}(g(X))=X$, hence if $g(X)$ is open, then so is $X$.